# Updating OrderedDict getting None

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Here is my list ,

```
z=[OrderedDict([('name', 'abc'), ('lastname', 'lastname.'), ('address', 'Mumbai'), ('cell', '21******')]), OrderedDict([('name', 'abc'), ('lastname', 'lastname.'), ('address', 'Mumbai'), ('cell', '21******')]), OrderedDict([('name', 'xyz'), ('lastname', 'lastnamexyz.'), ('address', 'Heaven'), ('cell', '2156******')])]
```

I am trying to change keys of this dictionary ,

What i am trying ,

```
>>> temp_lst=[]
>>> for i in z:
    newo=OrderedDict()
    temp_lst.append(newo.update(Name=i.get('name'),Lastname=i.get('lastname')))
>>> print temp_lst
    [None, None, None]
```

This code is printing tmp_lst as `[None, None, None]`

But when i have tried following , got the correct result.

```
>>> for i in z:
    newo=OrderedDict()
    newo.update(Name=i.get('name'),Lastname=i.get('lastname'))
    temp_lst.append(newo)   
>>> temp_lst
[OrderedDict([('Lastname', 'lastname.'), ('Name', 'abc')]), OrderedDict([('Lastname', 'lastname.'), ('Name', 'abc')]), OrderedDict([('Lastname', 'lastnamexyz.'), ('Name', 'xyz')])]
```

Both codes seems like the same then why i am getting `[None, None, None]` in first case and correct output in second case ?

Comment: `update` is in-place and returns `None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`dict.update`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) always returns `None`, so in the first example, you append `None` three times while in the second example, you append the dict object three times.

Answer (score 2):

because newo.update() doesn't return anything (so you get None).

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
temp_lst.append(newo.update(Name=i.get('name'),Lastname=i.get('lastname')))
```

You are actually adding the return value of `newo.update` to the list, which happens to be `None`. In the first example you first update the dict and then append the dict itself to `temp_lst`. That makes a difference